# Member not found for markup_text in dart (unable to find icons)

Tags: flutter, dart, markup

I added [markup_text](https://pub.dev/packages/markup_text/example) package to my yaml file and copied the code from their example to my dart file which gave me bunch of errors saying icon not found as shown in the screenshot below. I have tried `flutter pub upgrade` as well as `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` but error stays. how do I fix this?
[image]

Below is my `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.2 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2

  assets_audio_player: ^3.0.5
  firebase_analytics: ^10.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.0
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1

  lottie: ^2.0.0
  floodfill_image: ^0.0.8
  scribble: ^0.9.1
  pedometer: ^3.0.0
  permission_handler: ^9.2.0
  syncfusion_flutter_gauges: ^20.4.51
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.3
  hive: ^2.2.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.13
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  accordion: ^2.5.1
  camera: ^0.10.3+2
  simple_circular_progress_bar: ^1.0.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.1
  workmanager: ^0.5.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.0
  image_gallery_saver: '^1.7.1'
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Output of `flutter doctor` below:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.25)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Comment: According to the package, these icons come from the material package, so you just need to check if these error message icons still exist in the material package, if they don't exist you will have to edit the markup_text package and remove the missing icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[markup_text](https://pub.dev/packages/markup_text) 1.0.3 needs Flutter 3.10.0 to run. If you need to make it work with previous versions of Flutter you should use previous versions of the package.